# How to hide the soft navigation bar on Android with Titanium?

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Please can someone point to an example of how to hide the navigation bar on android, using Appcelerator.

NOT the action bar, nor the title bar. I can make these hide.
I want to make a completely fullscreen app, and hide the navigation bar

thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is called immersive fullscreen mode, it is possible to do it from android 4.4, but it seems that Titanium don't support the flag; there is [a module](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/27660#!overview) that does this thing, haven't personally tried it but probably will do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

In the tiapp.xml file:

```
<fullscreen>true</fullscreen>
<navbar-hidden>true</navbar-hidden>
```

In the app.tss or index.tss:

```
'Window':{
    navBarHidden:true,
    tabBarHidden:true,
    fullscreen:true
}
```

And in the index.js:

```
$.index.addEventListener("open",function() {

    if(OS_ANDROID) $.index.activity.actionBar.hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Ricardo,
But I may be missing something. I want the "back" & "home" buttons to disappear... 

I managed to capture the back button, and override the event. no luck with the other buttons.

Comment: That I don't know how to do it, even if it's possible, if you hide that bar and you don't have physical buttons how can you minimize or close the app?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is possible since Titanium 5.2 by using `<fullscreen>true</fullscreen>` in `tiapp.xml`.

See **Hide Soft Navigation Bar** in the [Release Notes](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_SDK_5.2.0_Release_Note-section-46245011_TitaniumSDK5.2.0ReleaseNote-AndroidPlatform).