# appcelerator titanium - hide navigation bar android

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, android-navigation-bar

Is it possible to hide permanently the Android bottom navigation in Appcelerator Titanium? Many questions about this subject but no fine solutions.

```
<fullscreen> true </fullscreen> 
in tiapp doesn't work with titanium 5.5.1

$.index.addEventListener('open', function(e) {   $.index.activity.actionBar.hide();}); 
doesn't work.

'Window':{navBarHidden:true,tabBarHidden:true,fullscreen:true} in tss 
doesn't work etc.
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This method always worked for me, set the app to fullscreen without nav bar and tab bar.

Assuming your main Window's id is not set or is set to 'index', only this should work, it's the approach that you've tried:

```
$.index.addEventListener('open', function(e) {

    $.index.activity.actionBar.hide();
});
```

In your app.tss or index.tss:

```
"Window":{
    navBarHidden:true,
    tabBarHidden:true,
    fullscreen:true
}
```

In your tiapp.xml:

```
<fullscreen>true</fullscreen>
<navbar-hidden>true</navbar-hidden>
```

If the issue it still the same, try to add this (specify theme) to the application or activity tags of the manifest section inside the tiapp.xml:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.NoActionBar"
```

Additional Info:

```
app.tss: global styles
index.tss: style for the index view
```

Verify if the id of the Window is correct, if there is any style overwriting the pretended one.

Add a console.log inside the window open method, you could check if exists all the action bar references:

```
if($.index) {

    console.log("window");

    if($.index.activity) {

        console.log("activity");

        if($.index.activity.actionBar) {

            console.log("action bar");

            if($.index.activity.actionBar.hide) {

                console.log("hide - try to hide");

                $.index.activity.actionBar.hide();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Check out this article at the Appcelerator Blog: [Hiding the Android ActionBar](http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2014/08/hiding-the-android-actionbar/)

If you're trying to hide the Soft Navigation Bar, I don't know it Titanium SDK as that option, but once I've answered a question, like yours, and Fokke Zandbergen comment this:

```
What you want is possible since Titanium 5.2 by using <fullscreen>true</fullscreen> in tiapp.xml.
```

[Android Documentation: Using Immersive Full-Screen Mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html)

[Appcelerator Documentation: Hide Soft Navigation Bar](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_SDK_5.2.0_Release_Note-section-46245011_TitaniumSDK5.2.0ReleaseNote-AndroidPlatform)

If all of this doesn't work you could try the following module:

[Appcelerator Module - Marketplace (free): 
Immersive view](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/27660#!overview)

Also found in the other question: [How to hide the soft navigation bar on Android with Titanium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35888880/how-to-hide-the-soft-navigation-bar-on-android-with-titanium)

Comment: Thank you Ricardo,

Comment: Thank you Ricardo, but i followed all your advices the console returned the correct answers :
[INFO] :   window
[INFO] :   activity
[INFO] :   action bar
[INFO] :   hide - try to hide
[WARN] :   ActionBarProxy: (main) [1593,1593] ActionBar is not enabled

But the android navigation bar is still displaying. I hope we speak about the same thing : i mean the bottom android navigation (Back/home/quit)…

Comment: Android version : 4.4.2

Comment: If you are talking about the operating system buttons, you can't disable those.

Comment: I've updated my answer, check out the last part of it