# Appcelerator - Android : hide status bar and navigation bar

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

I think i tried thousands of combinations, but after hours and hours i did not get any results. I'm trying to hide the STATUS BAR and the NAVIGATION BAR.

This is the actual result (only the splashscreen is ok) :

[image]
[image]

I read several tickets / questions.

- https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-19769
- https://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2014/08/hiding-the-android-actionbar/
- https://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2016/03/titanium-5-2-0-wrap-up-of-new-features-for-android/
- [appcelerator titanium - hide navigation bar android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40486261/appcelerator-titanium-hide-navigation-bar-android/)
- https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-4945

Solutions I've tried

## app.js

```
win.fullscreen = true / false;
win.navBarHidden = true / false;
```

## tiapp.xml

```
<fullscreen>true/false</fullscreen>
<navbar-hidden>false/false</navbar-hidden>
<statusbar-hidden>true/false</statusbar-hidden>
```

## tiapp.xml (section `<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">`)

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest>
        <application android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
    </manifest>
</android>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some build-in themes you can use on window level to hide the navigation/status bar on Android.

https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Android+Themes

So.. you can set it like this (in classic):

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    theme: "Theme.AppCompat.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
});
```

In Alloy you can set it globally easily by doing this in `app.tss`:

```
'Window': {
     theme: "Theme.AppCompat.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
}
```

Comment: In tiapp.xml how should i set the options (fullscreen / navbar-hidden)? Or the theme option override the options?

Comment: And the options fullscreen-navBarHidden of the window ? How should they be set?

Comment: navbarhidden: "Please note that this property will only take effect if the window is used inside a Titanium.UI.iOS.NavigationWindow and will be ignored otherwise."

Comment: fullscreen in tiapp: Since Release 5.0.0, on Android, the theme will be set to Theme.AppCompat.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen.

Comment: navbarhidden: Supported since Release 5.0.0 for Android. On Android, the theme will be set to Theme.AppCompat.NoTitleBar unless fullscreen or statusbar-hidden is set to true.

Comment: https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/tiapp.xml_and_timodule.xml_Reference-section-src-29004921_tiapp.xmlandtimodule.xmlReference-navbar-hidden

Comment: So they're all related to themes. Just setting the theme on a window will be sufficient

Comment: Thank you Rene... I tried to change the simulator, and now everything seems to work ... I do not understand, but the problem is solved.

Comment: The option fullscreen (true) seems to be enough to hide the bars on splashscreen and also on the app. It's possible?

Comment: Is it possible to customize the theme for all buttons? I would like to apply a transparent background to all the buttons, in order to eliminate the default style of the buttons on Android (padding, background and shadow).